# Web Page Session out issue (log out from application) - WebDriver-Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Our application is session out when no action/interaction is performed (idle) for 15 minutes of time as expected (in such a way that our application is developed)

But, My Automated script keep doing actions continuously with selenium - web driver, here Application getting session out and thinking that no actions are done, but actually script is doing actions.

Following are the ways I've tried out -

1. Catching locator for session out pop-up and refreshing browser, this is not suitable for me as previous data/actions gets refreshed (cleaned)
2. when session out pop-up displayed, used like selenium command SendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE/ENTER) but not working
3. Used Robot class working fine but not suitable solution in my case

Please provide any other solution to avoid session out issue

**Note**: Moving cursor on to the current web page when automated script is executing it may resolve the issue if any code in java for cursor on to webpage other than Robot class/key/mouse simulations

Answer (score 0):

If Robot works for you then may be Actions class of WebDriver can also work for you.

Here, I'm trying to move to an element, makes the page to scroll up or down as per element's visibility.

I hope this will help you..

```
public class TestCursorMove {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.get(baseUrl);           
            WebElement link_Home = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home"));
            WebElement td_Home = driver
                    .findElement(By
                    .xpath("//html/body/div"
                    + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
                    + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
                    + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
                    + "/table/tbody/tr"));    

            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            Action mouseOverHome = builder
                    .moveToElement(link_Home)
                    .build();

            String bgColor = td_Home.getCssValue("background-color");
            System.out.println("Before hover: " + bgColor);        
            mouseOverHome.perform();        
            bgColor = td_Home.getCssValue("background-color");
            System.out.println("After hover: " + bgColor);
            driver.close();
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks Hemanto for your help....!

This is worked background level, I mean to say DOM level but, I need mouse Cursor **icon** (physically) should be on the page (we should be able to see the mouse **Icon** on the page) while script running then only applications thinks that actions are doing on the page

Is there any solution, please help in this

Comment: I'd be able to suggest the best way, if I could play around with the application. Well, in this case, I can suggest you one more option.

If it's possible to maintain the session using the cookies then may be you can try following steps:

1. login to the app 
2. extract and save the cookies
3. reinsert the cookies to the browser when you come back

https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: I'll check that if it is handle by 'Cookies' to handle session out and update on this